# Android: Setting LiveData as MutableLiveData

Tags: android, mutablelivedata

Firstly i might not actually be understanding what mutable live data is correctly.

i get data from room using live data and then show it to the UI, it is a question with answers, so at the end of the question i would like to update the database with correct answers, the time it took etc etc.

I cannot work out how to use Mutable live data as there is next to no useful information on it or i'm incredibly stupid!

So firstly, can i actually update the database with mutable live data?

if so how? (i don't like asking this but i am a really stumped)

Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE :id = uoe_id")
LiveData<Question> getQuestionLiveData(int id);
```

Repo

```
public LiveData<Question> getQuestionLiveData(int id) {
  return questionDao.getQuestionLiveData(id);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public LiveData<Question> getQuestionLiveData(int id) {
  return questionRepository.getQuestionLiveData(id);
}
```

And then observing it in the View

```
viewModel.getQuestionLiveData(packageId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<com.questionTest.practice.Model.Question>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(com.questionTest.practice.Model.QuestionQuestion question) {

   Do stuff here////

                }
            }
        });
```

The next part is where i'm not sure. i added this in the view model

```
MutableLiveData mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
```

and then tried to assign the this to the question

```
mutableLiveData = (MutableLivedata) getQuestionLiveData(id);
```

so i could use update the values but this throws an Casting error.

Im either missing something or i cannot do this so any help will be welcomed thanks

Comment: Also new to this whole livedata thing. I think maybe look into Room? I haven't tried it myself, but maybe it is what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

In this case, There is no need for `MutableLiveData`. [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) is `LiveData` which publicly exposes `setValue()` and `postValue()` method. So if you are not setting `LiveData` values inside ViewModel class, there is no need for `MutableLiveData`. Here the Dao class generate `LiveData` for you and you should `observe` that `LiveData`.

Comment: but cant i use the mutable live data in a view model to update the database?

Comment: @Dave, No you can't. You can only set (or post) values and observe the changes. Use room architecture to update database.